# Can't get an object's class name in Python

Tags: python, class, object, types, isinstance

I'm using isinstance to check argument types, but I can't find the class name of a regex pattern object:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = re.compile('test')
>>> x.__class__.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __class__
```

...

```
>>> type(x)
<type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>
>>> isinstance(x, _sre.SRE_Pattern)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_sre' is not defined
>>>
>>>
>>> isinstance(x, '_sre.SRE_Pattern')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you do `import _sre`? What surprises you about the `NameError`?

Comment: @SilentGhost: `_sre` is an internal module, and does not reveal `SRE_Pattern` to the outside.

Comment: @poke: you wouldn't know it if you're not importing `_sre`

Comment: @SilentGhost: It didn't -- and still doesn't -- make much sense that an object wouldn't know itself or that it'd be in an outside module.

Comment: @zum: `x.__class__.__name__` works for me just fine in py3k. I'm not sure I'm following your *object know itself* charge.

Comment: @SilentGhost: x.__class__.__name__ doesn't work at 2.6. By "object, know thyself" I mean that in an OO language like Python I'd expect to be able to see an objects class and inheritance tree at the drop of a hat. It's also a matter of consistency, the x.__class__.__name__ chain works on all the built-in classes (str etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import re

pattern_type = type(re.compile("foo"))

if isinstance(your_object, pattern_type):
   print "It's a pattern object!"
```

The idiomatic way would be to try to use it as a pattern object, and then handle the resulting exception if it is not.

Comment: +1, that should be the safest way to do it.. Everything else will be dangerous given that the actual regexp implementation is inside the C core..

Answer (score 0):

```
In : x = re.compile('test')
In : isinstance(x, type(x))
Out: True

In [14]: type(type(x))
Out[14]: <type 'type'>
```

I think it relates to the type/object subtilities and to the **re** module implemetation. You can read a nice article [here](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html).